# In this “putting a price /pʊtɪŋ-ə- prʌɪs/”, is there /g/ in between?

Tags: pronunciation

> “**Putting a price** on carbon emissions has taken a heavy political toll in Australia.“
>   ([here](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/467) the presenter’s voice is linked; this is originally from Aussie [ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4045955.htm))

I hear, or I may be bewitched to hear, /g/ sound between /ŋ/ and /ə/ (schwa), in ‘*putting a price*’. Is there really /g/ or am I bewitched? If there is, can it be a certain pronouncing pattern concerning the /ŋ/ sound?

Comment: Historically, *-ing* **ɪŋg** coalesced into *-ing* **ɪŋ**, and as a result the *ng* spelling now most commonly represents **ŋ**, though *-ing* is often further reduced to **ɪn** (sometimes spelled *-in'*). A few dialects retain the original **g**, however, particularly in the north of England.  I don't hear it in this particular clip, but it's a bit fast and I haven't tried to analyze it with software, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @snailplane, [This matron](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/469) certainly pronounces 'ring' /ɪŋg/ way, doesn't she?

Comment: It sounds that way to me, except the third time around the final consonant release sounds voiceless to me.

Comment: Phonotactically it is unusual for the /g/ to be pronounced pre-vocalically, as it would almost certainly aspirate and sound like a /k/ as @snailplane suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You are not completely off; I do hear a bit of a velar stop in that clip. Whether it's voiced or unvoiced, I can't say for certain, but since both /ŋ/ and the following vowel would be voiced, I would imagine it is probably also voiced--that's what I'm hearing, but it might just be what I expect to hear.

Is there a general pronunciation rule here? I'm not really sure. I don't think the speaker intends to make that sound, but rather it's an effect of speaking rapidly with his accent (and also trying to enunciate clearly; he is a newscaster after all). I am looking for an American example, but haven't found one readily. In my own accent, I would probably (as Snailplane suggests) just drop the G, so /ŋ/ -> /n/. Unless trying to make the vowel separation very clear, I would never consciously pronounce a hard stop on a word ending in -ing.

Do you want to sound like this Australian newscaster? If you like his accent, this is one of many features of his speech you could probably try to imitate. But it wouldn't invalidate your use of English (or render it markedly non-native) to not do so.

In my opinion, it will mark your speech as non-native most if you are inconsistent about which accent features you emulate. But if your ear is good enough to catch this sound, I think you are probably going to be just fine.